# Trying to fetch by id from one table which has multiple answers in another table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.3

I have a questions table which contains all the questions. I also have a answers table which contains all the answers.
A question can have multiple answers and an answer belongs to only one question.
So the problem is how can i fetch a question by it's id and it should also have all the answers that belong to this question.

**Answer Model**

```
class Answer extends Model
{
    public function question()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Question');
    }
}
```

**Question Model**

```
class Question extends Model
{

    public function answers()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Answer');
    }
}
```

How can i write a query, I have tried few but I am confused now

Answer (score 0):

Every time you access **answers** attribute of a Question model Eloquent will load and return all related answers, so the following code will do the trick:

```
$answers = $question->answers;
```

When loading multiple questions you should consider using **eager-load** to load related answers in more efficient way - using one query for all questions instead of separate query for every question:

```
$questions = Question::with('answers')->get();
foreach ($questions as $question) {
  $questionAnswers = $question->answers;
}
```